# ¿Cómo actualizar valores de checkboxes insertados en un campo de una tabla de base de datos?

Tags: php, html

En un formulario de altas de un registro tengo lo siguiente con las `checkboxes`, `"aficiones"`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Alta de datos de usuario</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2><font color='blue'>Alta de datos - Rellene los campos de abajo:</font></h2>
    <form action="procesar_alta.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nombre" value="" maxlength="50" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contraseña:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="contrasenia" value="" maxlength="50" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comentario:</td> 
                <td><textarea name="comentario" rows="5" cols="80" maxlength="256" required /></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ciudad:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="ciudad" required>
                        <option value="">Elija una ciudad</option>
                        <option value="Quito">Quito</option>
                        <option value="Guayaquil">Guayaquil</option>
                        <option value="Cuenca">Cuenca</option>
                        <option value="Ambato">Ambato</option>
                        <option value="Tulcán">Tulcán</option>
                        <option value="Ibarra">Ibarra</option>
                        <option value="Pto. Baquerizo Moreno">Pto. Baquerizo Moreno</option>
                        <option value="Tena">Tena</option>
                        <option value="Puyo">Puyo</option>
                        <option value="Esmeraldas">Esmeraldas</option>
                        <option value="Portoviejo">Portoviejo</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <td>Región del Ecuador:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="region" value="Costa" required>Costa</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="region" value="Sierra">Sierra</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="region" value="Oriente">Oriente</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="region" value="Insular">Insular</input>                    
                    <br> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Aquí están las "checkboxes" aficiones -->
            <tr>
                <td>Aficiones:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="aficiones[musica]" value="NO">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="aficiones[musica]" value="musica"><label>Música</label> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="aficiones[aviones]" value="NO">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="aficiones[aviones]" value="aviones"><label>Aviones</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="aficiones[bicicleta]" value="NO">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="aficiones[bicicleta]" value="bicicleta"><label>Bicicleta</label>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
                  
            <tr>
                <td><input type="reset" name="borrar" value="Borrar" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="accion" value="Enviar" /></td>
            </tr>                      
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "modificaciondos";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ("Falló la conexión: " .$conn->connect_error);
}

echo "<h2><font color='red'>Resultados del proceso de alta de registro</font></h2>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Conexión a la BDD exitosa<br>";
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$contrasenia = $_POST['contrasenia'];
$comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
$region = $_POST['region'];
$aficiones = addslashes(implode(",", $_POST['aficiones']));
$sql = "INSERT INTO datos(nombre, contrasenia, comentario, ciudad, aficiones)
    VALUES ('$nombre', '$contrasenia', '$comentario', '$ciudad', '$aficiones')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "<br>¡Datos agregados a la tabla!";
    echo "<br><br>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " .$sql. "<br>" .mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo "<a href='index.php'>Volver a la pantalla de entrada</a>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Guardé los datos de los checkboxes escogidos mediante el siguiente código:

`aficiones = addslashes(implode(",", $_POST['aficiones']));`

Como un campo de un **`INSERT INTO`**. Esto guardaría la información recogida de las *checkboxes* como: `"musica,NO,bicicleta"` o `"musica,NO, NO"` o `"musica,aviones,bicicleta"`, depende, los tres valores separados con coma.

Ahora, la pregunta es ¿cómo modifico esos valores?. Por lo pronto se cómo recorrer el campo como una consulta, pero no lo puedo actualizar.

Comment: Intenta cambiar `name="aficiones[valor]" ` por `name=aficiones[]` opcionalmente puedes agregarle un **`id`** y luego iteras sobre `aficiones` en el script, lo que no entiendo es si tu problema reside en la sentencia `SQL` que utilizas o en el script.

Comment: No te recomiendo almacenar valores separados por coma en un campo, en su lugar podrías almacenar los datos en otra tabla y los relacionas por el ID del usuario.

Comment: Lo que @DjCrazy te aconseja sería lo ideal, otra forma es que en la misma tabla agregues campos por afición y lo manejes con cero o uno (0, 1) tal que, si marcan bicicletas pones 1 y sino la marcan pones 0. Pero a futuro te puede causar líos si cambian esas aficiones, así que puedes dejar nombres genéricos.

Answer (score 0):

Descubrí que el problema era tal vez **MySQL**, porque al estar probando generé muchos registros e implementé estos de los checkboxes a partir del registro 50 más o menos. Por eso pienso que la Base de Datos ya no quiso actualizar la columna de *aficiones*, que la agregué en ese momento a mi tabla de base de datos, pero luego, a partir del registro 87, eliminé la base de datos y la volví a crear y ya me actualizó el campo de las aficiones. El código de la parte de los checkboxes del formulario de ingreso de datos para modificarse es:

```html
<tr>
        <td>Aficiones:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="aficiones[musica]" value="NO">
            <input type="checkbox" name="aficiones[musica]" value="musica"><label>Música</label> 
            <input type="hidden" name="aficiones[aviones]" value="NO">
            <input type="checkbox" name="aficiones[aviones]" value="aviones"><label>Aviones</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="aficiones[bicicleta]" value="NO">
            <input type="checkbox" name="aficiones[bicicleta]" value="bicicleta"><label>Bicicleta</label>                     
        </td>
</tr>
```

El código del **archivo de procesamiento PHP** es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "modificaciondos";

$id = $_POST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$contrasenia = $_POST['contrasenia'];
$comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
$region = $_POST['region'];
// $aficiones = $_POST['aficiones'];
$aficiones = addslashes(implode(",", $_POST['aficiones']));


$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname);


$sql = "UPDATE datos SET nombre = '$nombre', contrasenia = '$contrasenia', comentario = '$comentario', 
ciudad = '$ciudad', region = '$region', aficiones = '$aficiones' WHERE id = '$id'";



/* Actualiza las filas */
echo "<h2><font color='red'>Datos Modificados</font></h2>";

mysqli_query($link, $sql);
printf("<font color='blue'>Número de registros Modificados: </font><font color='red'>%d\n</font>", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Volver a la pantalla de entrada</a>";
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Para actualizar el campo aficiones, también se usa el código: `$aficiones = addslashes(implode(",", $_POST['aficiones']));`

Eso es todo lo que pasó.